# Entrando na aplicação móvel do Stack Exchange não conta como dia consecutivo?

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, login, mobile

Este fim de semana entrei no sábado e no domingo na aplicação [Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) da *play store* da Google e não contou como dias consecutivos, recomeçando a contagem.

Entrando nessa aplicação não conta para os dias consecutivos?

E se for no *browser* do Android ou no [Chrome mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome)?

Comment: Se não me engano, a gente tem que executar alguma ação (mobile ou desktop) para contar o dia.

Comment: Exatamente o que disse o brasofilo: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app

Comment: Jorge, seus [feeds de atividade pública](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7210/jorge-b?tab=activity) (meta e main) mostram um gap dos dias 6 e 7 até o dia 10. Você chegou a votar em alguma coisa?

Comment: @brasofilo falta-me só o dia 8. Não me recordo se tive atividade, só que entrei na app. No PC se calhar nunca reparei nisso porque se calhar tenho atividade todos os dias.

Comment: Já agora aquele calendário está bem ranhoso. Aquela transparência não fica nada bem.

Comment: @brasofilo Coloca com resposta o teu comentário, até com link para o METÃO que o bfavaretto referiu para dar esse assunto como resolvido.

Comment: @brasofilo responde para que seja possível fechar eventuais duplicatas.